# How to modify bubble sort code to show results in decimal number in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, x86-16, bubble-sort

So, I have this code given by the professor and when you execute it, it will sort the numbers in the array. The display will show them as hex. I'm asked to modify this code so that they will be displayed as decimals. Tried some subroutines ,I've found on the internet but still nothing.The program I'm using is called masm and it runs on dosbox.

```
.486                

DISP MACRO X

    push ax
    push dx
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset X
    int 21h
    pop dx
    pop ax

ENDM

STACK_SEG segment para STACK    

    db 256 dup (0)

STACK_SEG ends


DATA_SEG segment  para public   

     array dw 9,18,118,6,325,4,-9,2,1

     array_str equ (($-array)/2)

    ;arr_sz db 255
    ;array_str db 1 dup(0)
    ;array dw 100 dup(0)

     in_mes db 'Insert number'
        db '$'

     buffer db 4 dup(0)
        db '$'
     mes db 10,13
        db '$'
     swap_count db 1 dup(1)
DATA_SEG ends


CODE_SEG segment USE16 para public 'CODE'   

    assume cs:code_seg,ds:data_seg


START:              

main proc far       

    ; Set up stack for return

    push ds
    mov ax,0
    push ax

    ; Set DS register to current data segment

    mov ax,data_seg
    mov ds ,ax          




    disp mes
    call disp_arr
    disp mes
    disp mes




next_pass:
    mov al,swap_count
    cmp al,0
    je done
    mov swap_count,0
    mov di,0
next_elm:
    shl di,1
    mov ax, array[di]
    cmp ax, array[di+2]
    jg swap
increment:
    shr di,1
    inc di
    mov al, array_str
    and ax,0Fh
    cmp di, ax
    je next_pass
    jmp next_elm
swap:
    inc swap_count
    mov bx,array[di+2]
    mov array[di+2],ax
    mov array[di],bx
    jmp increment
done:


    call disp_arr
    disp mes
    disp mes
    ret             

main endp           

HEX2ASCII PROC NEAR



    push    bp
    mov     bp,sp
    mov     ax,[bp+4]   

    push    cx

    mov     cx,4
    mov     bp,cx

 H2A1:

    push    ax
    and     al,0Fh     
    add     al,30h
    cmp     al,'9'
    jbe     H2A2
    add     al,7h

 H2A2:

    dec     cx
    mov     bp,cx
    mov buffer[bp],al

    pop     ax
    ror     ax,4        
    jnz     H2A1

    pop     cx
    pop     bp

    ret 2

HEX2ASCII ENDP

disp_arr PROC NEAR


    push di
    mov di,0
lp1:
    push di
    shl di,1
    mov ax, array[di]
    push ax
    call HEX2ASCII
    disp buffer
    disp mes
    pop di
    inc di
    mov al, array_str
    and ax,0fh
    cmp di, ax
    jb lp1
    pop di


    ret

disp_arr ENDP

CODE_SEG ends       

END START
```

Comment: _"Tried some subroutines ,I've found on the internet but still nothing."_ That's very vague, and doesn't really tell us anything useful. In any case, questions about how to convert integers to strings in x86 assembly have been asked lots of times before. Do some searching.

Comment: Wow..  Your instructor has gone very easy on you.  All that you need to do is use his `HEX2ASCII` routine as a sample and write something that will convert the hex numbers to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Even before trying to change this program so it displays decimals instead of hexadecimals, there are several problems:

- The *HEX2ASCII* procedure uses `mov buffer[bp],al` with the *buffer* located in the DS addressable *DATA_SEG* but the use of `BP` implies that SS segment register will be used! Either insert a `DS:` segment override prefix or use another register like `BX` (Remember to `push`/`pop` it).
- When the *disp* macro is used to display the buffer contents, it does so by starting at the 1st byte of this buffer but because of the early exit method adopted by the *HEX2ASCII* procedure the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd bytes can/will contain garbage!

This is a version of *HEX2ASCII* that does not need changes to the way *disp* works. It does not exit prematuraly and so you can safely display 4 digits for every number.

```
HEX2ASCII PROC NEAR
 push    bp
 mov     bp,sp
 mov     ax,[bp+4]
 push    bx

 mov     bx,4
H2A1:
 push    ax
 and     al,0Fh     
 add     al,30h
 cmp     al,'9'
 jbe     H2A2
 add     al,7h
H2A2:
 dec     bx
 mov     buffer[bx],al
 pop     ax
 ror     ax,4        
 test    bx,bx
 jnz     H2A1

 pop     bx
 pop     bp
 ret 2
```

---

In the conversion to hexadecimal the `and al,0Fh` and `ror ax,4`instructions play a key role. They (kind of) perform a division by **16**.
In the conversion to decimal you'll need a division by **10**. You'll have to use the `div` instruction, convert the remainder to text as before, and continu the algorithm with the quotient.